# Pentax DA L lens focusing scale?

Tags: lens, pentax, manual-focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one focus for landscape photos in very dark conditions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/how-does-one-focus-for-landscape-photos-in-very-dark-conditions)

I have a Pentax K-r with the kit DA L 18-55 and a prime DA 35. As far as I'm concerned, they are good lenses indeed. However, there's one little annoyance: they doesn't have a focusing scale!

I like doing night time long exposure photography. Obviously, with the scene in the viewfinder almost pitch black, there's almost no way the AF system or my eyes can get a good focus on the subject. So, I guess it would be nice to have focusing scale in the lens isn't it? Do anyone know the focusing scale on those (and maybe more) "scale-less" lens?

Answer (score 2):

I also do long expsosure night time photography. I use a laser or a spotlight to enable accurate focussing.

Comment: Nice idea! Is laser can really aid focusing?

Comment: Laser work for me but it wont light up the space station like someone was asking to focus on :)